# makeing a terms of use page that is part of the theme

Tags: theme-development, pages

I need to make a "terms of use" page.  The only way I see to do so involves the user needing to manually add a page in the admin.  But I need to implement it as an integral part of the theme.  Is there a way to create a custom template file and create a link that will que Wordpress to access it without needing to manually add a page for it?  Is there a way to programaticaly add pages to a wordpress site through the theme's functions.php file.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create a new template file in order to create a terms of use page.  I implemented what I need by simply modifying index.php.  The "terms of use" page is accessed by linking to http://homeurl?section=terms.  Then add php code in index.php to check if `$_Get["section"] == 'terms'`.  If so display the markup for "terms of use".  If not then, display the regular home page.